# How can I bind a key to switch to a specific workspace in XMonad?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm running a two headed setup, and I'd very much like to bind like `M-i` to switch the left monitor's workspace to workspace 5, and the right monitor's workspace to workspace 6.

I've taken a look through `Xmonad.Actions`, but I couldn't see what I was looking for.

Something like

```
xmonad `additionalKeysP` [("M-i", switchToWorkspaces)]
```

where `switchToWorkspace` is the function I'm after

Answer (score 4):

Use [XMonad.Actions.OnScreen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-OnScreen.html#v:onScreen):

```
windows (greedyViewOnScreen 0 "5" . greedyViewOnScreen 1 "6")
```

Comment: At first I thought this worked, but it seems that it doesn't actually function as quite I expected. Changing greedyViewOnScreen to viewOnScreen gives a better effect.